# What does "rep change" mean?

Tags: support, reputation-history

I noticed that my reputation jumped from 71 to 122. I didn't see any reputation changes in "reputation tab", until I unfolded reputation earned for 8 May.

There was something strange - "rep change":

> [image]

What is it?

What can cause it?

Comment: Maybe a recalculation took place?

Comment: @rene I open meta.stackexchange.com/reputation every day and don't see something strange

Comment: That page does exist but I don't think it is still accurate...

Comment: Rep changes still exists.

Comment: @AdamLear Was it intended that the system no longer work this way? Is that why this has been closed as something that "can no longer be reproduced"? [This is continuing to happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359568/what-does-the-rep-change-explanation-in-the-reputation-tab-mean), so I've voted to reopen this.

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, I closed it back when I lived in a happier, more naive time and didn't know as much about our rep code as I do now.This definitely still applies. Thanks for reopening.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This happens when a post that gave you sufficient rep to give a bounty was subsequently removed.

After a rep-recalc, the system finds that you no longer had enough rep to "have given" the bounty. But of course it can't turn back time and change the past. Instead, it gives you that rep for free.

So a sequence of events such as this: (the exact numbers will be different for everyone)

1. Start with 1 rep.
2. Post an answer that 10 upvotes and earns you 100 rep.
3. Bounty away the 100 rep.
4. Your answer with 10 upvotes gets deleted thereby removing the 100 rep you gained from it.

Notice that you lost 100 rep *twice* (once from the bounty and once from the deletion). But you only had 101 rep prior to the bounty. That means that you'll have negative rep.

Since everyone has at least 1 rep, the system will "give" you enough rep to get back to 1. This would be recorded as a "+100 rep change".

Comment: I have awarded only one bounty, worth 350 rep, the post still does exist.

Comment: If you click on "show removed posts", I bet you'll see that something big got deleted. That was the post that gave you enough rep in the first place to give that bounty.

Comment: No. I don't see and know that I won't. I have started 4 bounties, total - 500 rep, no bounty of these bounties was removed.

Comment: @Not the post that you bountied. It's a post that belongs to *you* for which you earned enough rep to give the bounty in the first place.

Comment: A! Understood!.. There was such a post, but I undeleted it because it gave me rep.

Comment: @nicael are you trying to drive your rep to zero by giving bounties and deleting anything that earns you rep?

Comment: But I didn't try to "drive your rep to zero" when I asked this question, I write that rep jumped from **71** to 122