# My Reputation graph in network profile is wrong

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation-graph

Look [there](https://stackexchange.com/users/3548243/nicael?tab=reputation). It shows that my reputation on Stack Overflow is 1,553. Actually, it is 2,081.

Now look at April 20. It shows that my rep on SO was 259, and my rep on MSE was 129. Wrong, again. That day it was 730 on SO and 101 on MSE - I have just registered on MSE.

Then look at May, 15. It shows 1,323 on SO and 174 on MSE. Actually, I had 1860 rep on SO and, well 167 on MSE, almost right. Now it shows right rep for MSE and completely wrong for SO and shows negative rep for a period since April 10 to April 16 .

---

/reputation:

```
total votes: 1309
 2  19853362 (10)
-- 2013-11-08 rep +10   = 11        
 2  19875930 (10)
-- 2013-11-09 rep +10   = 21        
 2  19876868 (10)
-- 2013-11-11 rep +10   = 31        
-- 2013-11-12 rep 0     = 31        
 3  19950944 (-1)
-- 2013-11-13 rep -1    = 30        
-- 2013-11-15 rep 0     = 30        
-- 2013-11-16 rep 0     = 30        
-- 2013-11-17 rep 0     = 30        
-- 2013-11-26 rep 0     = 30        
 3  19042364 (-1)
-- 2013-11-27 rep -1    = 29        
 3  20269669 (-2)
 3  20269669 (-2)
 3  20269669 (-2)
 3  20269669 (-2)
 3  20269669 (-2)
 2  20269669 (5)
 3  20269669 (-2)
 2  20269669 (5)
 2  20269669 (5)
 2  20269669 (5)
 2  20269669 (5)
 2  20269669 (5)
-- 2013-11-28 rep +18   = 47        
 1  20285874 (2)
 1  20270525 (2)
 2  20288609 (5)
 1  20288650 (2)
 3  20288609 (-2)
-- 2013-11-29 rep +9    = 56        
 16 20299742 (2)
 16 20299957 (2)
 3  20285404 (-2)
-- 2013-11-30 rep +2    = 58        
-- 2013-12-01 rep 0     = 58        
-- 2013-12-15 rep 0     = 58        
-- 2013-12-18 rep 0     = 58        
-- 2013-12-25 rep 0     = 58        
-- 2014-01-05 rep 0     = 58        
 2  20101469 (5)
-- 2014-02-10 rep +5    = 63        
 2  20101469 (5)
-- 2014-02-14 rep +5    = 68        
-- 2014-04-01 rep 0     = 68        
 1  22814578 (2)
-- 2014-04-02 rep +2    = 70        
 3  22846204 (-2)
 2  22846204 (5)
-- 2014-04-03 rep +3    = 73        
 1  22846482 (2)
 1  22866553 (2)
-- 2014-04-04 rep +4    = 77        
 16 19680907 (2)
 16 22554131 (2)
 16 22882120 (2)
 16 22882083 (2)
 16 22882283 (2)
 16 22882253 (2)
 16 22882230 (2)
 16 22882389 (2)
 16 22882372 (2)
 16 22882427 (2)
 16 22882547 (2)
 16 22882519 (2)
 16 22882444 (2)
 16 22882679 (2)
 16 22882791 (2)
 16 22882761 (2)
 16 22882797 (2)
 16 22882962 (2)
 16 22883030 (2)
 16 22882992 (2)
 16 22883063 (2)
 16 22883091 (2)
 16 22883112 (2)
 16 22883267 (2)
 16 22884050 (2)
 16 22884478 (2)
 16 22884538 (2)
 16 22884593 (2)
 16 22884903 (2)
 1  22871567 (2)
 16 22885548 (2)
 16 22885617 (2)
 16 22885724 (2)
 2  22884393 (10)
-- 2014-04-05 rep +76   = 153       
 16 22890351 (2)
 16 22890290 (2)
 16 22890364 (2)
 16 22890386 (2)
 16 22890400 (2)
 16 22890432 (2)
 2  22890703 (5)
 1  22890730 (2)
 16 22891191 (2)
 1  22893458 (2)
 16 22893596 (2)
 2  22893937 (10)
 1  22893937 (15)
-- 2014-04-06 rep +50   = 203       
 16 22915436 (2)
 1  22915419 (15)
 2  22916393 (10)
 2  22916393 (10)
 2  22916393 (10)
 16 22917181 (2)
 16 22918060 (2)
 1  22918496 (15)
 2  22919791 (10)
 3  22919791 (-2)
 2  22894063 (10)
-- 2014-04-07 rep +84   = 287       
 16 22935776 (2)
 16 22935819 (2)
 2  22936509 (10)
 16 22936654 (2)
 2  22937901 (5)
 2  22937901 (5)
 2  22937901 (5)
 1  22937930 (2)
 2  22939126 (10)
 1  22944171 (2)
 2  22884393 (10)
 3  22944104 (-2)
 2  22936509 (10)
-- 2014-04-08 rep +63   = 350       
 16 22959884 (2)
 2  22944844 (10)
 2  22962179 (10)
 1  22966829 (2)
 16 22969028 (2)
 2  22969476 (10)
 2  22969476 (10)
 1  22962179 (15)
 2  22969476 (10)
 2  22969346 (10)
 2  22970786 (10)
-- 2014-04-09 rep +91   = 441       
 3  22944844 (-2)
 1  22939126 (15)
-- 2014-04-10 rep +13   = 454       
 1  22937468 (15)
-- 2014-04-16 rep +15   = 469       
 16 23132268 (2)
 1  23132150 (15)
 2  23132150 (10)
 2  23136999 (10)
 16 23137250 (2)
 16 23137270 (2)
 16 23137283 (2)
 16 23103101 (2)
 2  23139149 (10)
 1  23139149 (15)
-- 2014-04-17 rep +70   = 539       
 2  23155918 (10)
 2  23155918 (10)
 1  23155918 (15)
 1  23156118 (15)
-- 2014-04-18 rep +50   = 589       
-- bonuses   (100)
 2  23171575 (10)
 1  23171575 (15)
 2  23171575 (10)
 2  23156118 (10)
-- 2014-04-19 rep +145  = 734       
 16 23178659 (2)
 16 23178659 (2)
 16 23179146 (2)
 16 23179188 (2)
 16 23179243 (2)
 16 23179248 (2)
 1  23179405 (15)
-- 2014-04-20 rep +27   = 761       
-- 2014-04-21 rep 0     = 761       
-- 2014-04-22 rep 0     = 761       
 16 23245570 (2)
 2  23251848 (10)
 1  23251848 (15)
 3  23251662 (-1)
 8  22881919 (-50)
-- 2014-04-23 rep -24   = 737       
 3  23265154 (-1)
 2  23265602 (10)
 2  23265602 (10)
 16 23265655 (2)
 3  23265602 (-2)
 16 23267017 (2)
 16 23266612 (2)
 3  23267694 (-2)
 3  23267694 (-2)
 16 23267724 (2)
 16 23267773 (2)
 16 23267827 (2)
 2  23267694 (10)
 16 23267910 (2)
 16 23267936 (2)
 16 23267950 (2)
 16 23267972 (2)
 16 23268063 (2)
 16 23268010 (2)
 16 23268097 (2)
 16 23268133 (2)
 16 23268202 (2)
 16 23268284 (2)
 16 23268233 (2)
 16 23268287 (2)
 16 23269541 (2)
 16 23269593 (2)
 16 23269674 (2)
 16 23269289 (2)
 16 23269855 (2)
-- 2014-04-24 rep +69   = 806       
 2  23295469 (10)
 16 23300252 (2)
 2  23300473 (10)
-- 2014-04-25 rep +22   = 828       
 2  23264530 (10)
 1  23264530 (15)
 16 23311005 (2)
 2  23311320 (10)
 1  23311814 (15)
 2  23311999 (10)
 2  23312284 (10)
 2  23311999 (10)
 2  23311814 (10)
 3  23267694 (-2)
 2  22881919 (5)
 2  23311149 (10)
 1  23311149 (15)
-- 2014-04-26 rep +120  = 948       
 3  23322625 (-2)
 2  23322625 (10)
 2  23322625 (10)
-- 2014-04-27 rep +18   = 966       
 2  23343682 (10)
 1  23343682 (15)
 2  23346630 (10)
 2  23346630 (10)
 2  23346630 (10)
 1  23346630 (15)
 3  23348720 (-2)
 2  23348720 (10)
 2  23348720 (10)
 2  23349433 (10)
 1  23349912 (15)
 2  23349912 (10)
 1  23350358 (15)
 3  23348720 (-2)
-- 2014-04-28 rep +136  = 1102      
 2  23356395 (10)
 2  23365079 (10)
 2  23366362 (10)
 2  23366362 (10)
 2  23367379 (10)
 2  23368866 (10)
 2  23368866 (10)
 2  23368866 (10)
 1  23324445 (15)
 1  23374775 (2)
-- 2014-04-29 rep +97   = 1199      
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 2  22881919 (5)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 2  22881919 (5)
 3  22881919 (-2)
 3  22881919 (-2)
-- 2014-04-30 rep -20   = 1179      
 16 23421201 (2)
-- 2014-05-04 rep +2    = 1181      
 1  22968948 (2)
 16 23477648 (2)
 16 23480697 (2)
 16 23481946 (2)
-- 2014-05-05 rep +8    = 1189      
 16 23500348 (2)
 2  23500736 (10)
 2  23503454 (10)
 2  23504067 (10)
 2  23504067 (10)
 2  23504067 (10)
 1  23504067 (15)
-- 2014-05-06 rep +67   = 1256      
 2  23524410 (10)
 2  23524410 (10)
-- 2014-05-07 rep +20   = 1276      
-- 2014-05-08 rep 0     = 1276      
 1  23544588 (15)
 16 23568820 (2)
 2  23568843 (5)
 1  23569589 (2)
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23569087 (10)
-- 2014-05-09 rep +39   = 1315      
 2  23581634 (10)
 16 23572072 (2)
 16 23480416 (2)
 16 23453428 (2)
 16 23459245 (2)
 16 23456868 (2)
 16 22760839 (2)
 16 22734636 (2)
 16 23005177 (2)
 16 22837139 (2)
 16 22878183 (2)
 16 22458712 (2)
 16 22369922 (2)
 16 22379316 (2)
 16 22234485 (2)
 16 22596469 (2)
 16 21899332 (2)
 16 21663627 (2)
 16 22100276 (2)
 16 21957113 (2)
 16 21668148 (2)
 16 22074115 (2)
 16 21504613 (2)
 16 21402607 (2)
 16 20654826 (2)
 16 21884326 (2)
 16 19929893 (2)
 16 21743718 (2)
 16 19851494 (2)
 16 20437131 (2)
 16 19639465 (2)
 16 20528401 (2)
 16 19974285 (2)
 16 20018171 (2)
 16 20102792 (2)
 16 20025344 (2)
 16 20283608 (2)
 16 20026805 (2)
 16 19358156 (2)
 16 19472615 (2)
 16 18804985 (2)
 16 19371911 (2)
 16 18812190 (2)
 16 18737539 (2)
 16 18755075 (2)
 16 18807310 (2)
 16 19437481 (2)
 16 18837281 (2)
 16 18837937 (2)
 16 19278859 (2)
 16 19331899 (2)
 16 19351065 (2)
 16 18361696 (2)
 16 18437162 (2)
 16 18392803 (2)
 16 18430656 (2)
 16 18334438 (2)
 16 18361143 (2)
 16 18331572 (2)
 16 18316110 (2)
 16 18385671 (2)
 16 18378993 (2)
 16 18287533 (2)
 16 18098055 (2)
 16 18065400 (2)
 16 18244726 (2)
 16 17495273 (2)
 16 18037752 (2)
 16 17523814 (2)
 16 17415464 (2)
 16 17078947 (2)
 16 16821879 (2)
 16 17158825 (2)
 16 16921136 (2)
 16 16915118 (2)
 16 16702797 (2)
 16 16698213 (2)
 16 16682328 (2)
 16 16599183 (2)
 16 16582677 (2)
 16 15984087 (2)
 16 16221359 (2)
 16 15960511 (2)
 16 15833060 (2)
 16 15463831 (2)
 16 15639293 (2)
 16 14803222 (2)
 16 15417174 (2)
 16 15629552 (2)
 16 14784483 (2)
 16 14446506 (2)
 16 14046400 (2)
 16 14339844 (2)
 16 14091707 (2)
 16 15184803 (2)
 16 13908329 [2]
 16 13474786 [0]
 16 13390401 [0]
 3  22937901 [-2]
 16 13364105 [2]
 16 13792980 [0]
 16 13345191 [0]
 16 13094536 [0]
 16 13271961 [0]
 16 13034935 [0]
 16 12998200 [0]
 16 13371811 [0]
-- 2014-05-10 rep +200  = 1515      
 1  23584504 (15)
 16 23589291 (2)
 1  23589578 (15)
 1  23590361 (15)
 2  23590463 (10)
 2  23590463 (10)
 2  23592412 (10)
 1  23592412 (15)
 2  23593070 (10)
 16 23593672 (2)
 2  23594122 (10)
 2  23594122 (10)
 1  23590463 (15)
 2  23596023 (10)
 16 19146341 (2)
 16 18848457 (2)
 16 19075472 (2)
 16 19121048 (2)
 16 18949689 (2)
 16 18901669 (2)
 16 18944800 (2)
 16 18812190 (2)
 16 18667253 (2)
 16 18615939 (2)
 16 17634245 (2)
 16 17700216 (2)
 16 17825728 (2)
 16 16905035 (2)
 16 17440926 (2)
 16 17224842 (2)
 16 17407918 (2)
 16 22920900 (2)
 16 21397021 (2)
 16 19752843 (2)
 16 21153697 (2)
 16 19959953 (2)
 16 11585030 (2)
 16 11136217 (2)
 16  9256661 (2)
 16 10941588 (2)
 16  9089532 (2)
 16  7582540 (2)
 16 11550066 (2)
 16  6792542 (2)
 16 12557180 (2)
 16  6853865 (2)
 16  6327157 (2)
 16  5963182 (2)
 16  6279292 (2)
 16  4425885 (2)
 16  4032495 (2)
 16  3503471 (2)
 16  2882861 (2)
 16   383185 (2)
 16  2819837 (2)
 16   383172 (2)
 16   383189 (2)
 16  2739515 (2)
 16  1026495 (2)
 16   502138 (2)
 16   386044 (2)
 16   385960 (2)
 16   383201 (2)
 16   458453 (2)
 16   390992 (2)
 16   366031 (2)
 16   366047 (2)
 16   109399 (2)
 16   402538 (2)
 16 12431597 (2)
 16  3863454 (2)
 16 18527447 (2)
 16 17256961 (2)
-- 2014-05-11 rep +267  = 1782      
 2  23581634 (10)
 1  23581634 (15)
 16 23601636 (2)
 2  23612559 (10)
-- 2014-05-12 rep +37   = 1819      
 1  23612559 (15)
-- 2014-05-13 rep +15   = 1834      
 2  23663537 (10)
-- 2014-05-14 rep +10   = 1844      
 2  23682737 (10)
 3  23682737 (-2)
 1  23682737 (15)
 8  23568843 (-50)
-- 2014-05-15 rep -27   = 1817      
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23697058 (10)
 2  23663537 (10)
 2  23697058 (10)
-- 2014-05-16 rep +35   = 1852      
 2  23716348 (10)
-- 2014-05-17 rep +10   = 1862      
 2  23718863 (10)
 1  22630013 (2)
 2  23722781 (5)
 2  23722572 (10)
 2  23722781 (5)
 1  23723036 (2)
 2  23722491 (10)
 1  23722572 (15)
 2  23568843 (5)
 16 23726152 (2)
 16 23726188 (2)
-- 2014-05-18 rep +68   = 1930      
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23742849 (10)
 2  23737776 (5)
-- 2014-05-19 rep +35   = 1965      
-- 2014-05-20 rep 0     = 1965      
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23568843 (5)
 16 23784203 (2)
 16 23786765 (2)
 16 23786950 (2)
 2  23787428 (10)
 2  23568843 (5)
 3  23787428 (-2)
-- 2014-05-21 rep +29   = 1994      
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23568843 (5)
 3  23808466 (-1)
 2  23504067 (10)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23524410 (10)
-- 2014-05-22 rep +44   = 2038      
 8  23737776 (-50)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
-- 2014-05-24 rep -35   = 2003      
-- 2014-05-25 rep 0     = 2003      
 2  23568843 (5)
 2  23872599 (10)
-- 2014-05-26 rep +15   = 2018      
 2  23179405 (10)
 2  22915419 (10)
 3  23737776 (-2)
 2  23737776 (5)
 3  23737776 (-2)
-- 2014-05-27 rep +21   = 2039      
-- 2014-05-28 rep 0     = 2039      
 2  22937468 (10)
-- 2014-05-29 rep +10   = 2049      
 2  23737776 (5)
 3  23737776 (-2)
 2  23737776 (5)
-- 2014-05-30 rep +8    = 2057      
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  23737776 (5)
 1  23848870 (2)
-- 2014-05-31 rep +12   = 2069      
 2  23568843 (5)
-- 2014-06-01 rep +5    = 2074      
 3  23737776 (-2)
 2  23993579 (5)
 3  23993579 (-2)
 2  23993579 (5)
 2  20268024 (10)
-- 2014-06-02 rep +16   = 2090      
 1  23993660 (2)
 1  24020507 (15)
 2  24020625 (10)
 2  24020625 (10)
 3  24020507 (-2)
 2  24020625 (10)
 2  24020625 (10)
-- 2014-06-03 rep +55   = 2145      
 2  23737776 (5)
 2  24042138 (10)
 2  24020625 (10)
-- 2014-06-04 rep +25   = 2170      
 1  24042138 (15)
-- 2014-06-05 rep +15   = 2185      

** rep today: 15
** rep this week (2014-06-01 - 2014-06-07): 116
** rep this month (2014-06-01 - 2014-06-30): 116
** rep this quarter (2014-04-01 - 2014-06-30): 2117
** rep this year (2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31): 2127
** rep from bonuses: 100
** total rep 2185 :)
```

Comment: It's also showing you had negative reputation on a few days, which just shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes, -48. Really strange.

Comment: @nicael - You are right, I misread it.

Comment: What do you see when you go to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)?

Comment: @Emrakul It shows my actual rep, without any surprises.

Comment: @nicael Is the total reputation at any point negative?

Comment: @Emrakul No. It is negative in graph only.

Comment: It'd be interesting if you could share the output of the [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) link. You might want to sanitize it by removing the lines with `(-1)` which is answers you downvoted. Then someone could make a new graph, compare it with the SE graph, and find what caused the discrepancy. My guess is it's the `rep change` events, but obviously can't say for sure

Comment: @mhlester done. I haven't got any "rep change" events on SO, only [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231808/what-does-rep-change-mean).

Comment: @Anna looks like Nick found the reason, so nothing weird anymore. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've graphed the data from your [SE graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3548243/nicael?tab=reputation) and your [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page:

[image]

---

#### Analyzing that data, I found a discrepancy on 22 days

On these days, the graph increased more than /reputation:

```
Date       Graph  /rep   Diff
2013-11-11    50    10     40
2013-11-15    70     0     70
2013-11-17    10     0     10
2013-11-26    55     0     55
2013-11-28   126    18    108
2013-11-29   147     9    138
2013-11-30    10     2      8
2014-04-02   160     2    158
2014-04-09   106    91     15
2014-04-29   107    97     10
2014-05-11   269   267      2
2014-05-16    50    35     15
2014-05-18    83    68     15
```

And on these days /reputation increased more than the graph:

```
Date       Graph  /rep   Diff
2013-12-01  -129     0    129
2014-04-03  -105     3    108
2014-04-04  -126     4    130
2014-04-05    72    76      4
2014-04-10  -720    13    733
2014-04-30   -30   -20     10
2014-05-19     5    35     30
2014-05-25   -10     0     10
2014-06-03    53    55      2
```

Looking at your reputation [history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2), for `2014-04-10`, the largest discrepancy, I see this:

> [image]

Spot checking other days from the second group, they all seem to have a `User was removed` entry. The first group likely represents the days those users *voted* on your posts.

---

## Conclusion:

- The /reputation page shows no data on removed users, as if they'd never existed
- The reputation profile page shows removed users on the date they were removed, and earlier votes are still displayed on the day of the vote.
- The reputation graph on SE does *both of these!* It seems to remove votes in the manner of /reputation, but then also removes reputation **a second time** on the date the user was removed.

Comment: Many thanks! Very useful! If anyone won't provide me an explanations why it happened, I'll give you this bounty.

Answer (score 5):

After the cleanup [that happened here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234279/about-rep-changes-and-gaming-system-using-them/234347) just now, the SE.com profile page should be correct after the next pull that'll happen tonight around midnight UTC. Peripheral systems like this are why cleanup on history was necessary here.

Comment: The graph doesn't appear to have changed. Are you sure the graph isn't double-counting `user was removed` events? See my answer here. It seems to solve the problem

Comment: Really, my SO rep is -323 now, could you fix it plz.

Comment: It is not completed. Please either complete it or remove [status-completed].

Comment: Plzzzzzzz fixxx it!

Comment: @nicael this is the result of multiple sock puppet accounts being deleted, bounties awarded you did not have rep for, and non-standard reputation fixes to account for the differences in both with are pretty much specific to you. This isn't something we'll invest dev time in anytime soon. Do you really want to go down the road of why your reputation is so far off? The quickest solution for us here is to wipe the slate and not have your colorful history be and insane outlier, rather than patch around an issue for a few of over 5 million accounts in the same boat - self created in each case.

Comment: @Nick can you please update the answer as well to reflect the reason of declining the request? (different wording of course)

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your great effort!!! And update the answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

> **Disclaimer**: this is not the official answer, just explaining why this bug report is declined.

As Nick explains in a comment, this behavior is specific to the OP here who has done lots of things that, to put it nicely, should not really have been done.

Since this will not happen to all other millions of users, the request to fix this one instance was declined.